# protect bytes data .net

Tags: .net, security, data-protection

am trying to protect bytes data using the protectedmemory and protecteddata in .net application

form this site, http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/Framework/69_Data_Encryption_and_Decryption_using_DPAPI_classes_in_NET.aspx
 is seems i can only protect a few bytes

and also, i cannot get the sample provided here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741(v=vs.85).aspx to run

I get the following errors:

> Name 'MemoryProtectionScope' is not declared. (BC30451)
>      Name 'DataProtectionScope' is not declared. (BC30451)
>      Name 'ProtectedMemory' is not declared. (BC30451)

can anyone help me with other methods of doing this.

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Security. Those types are defined in that assembly.

Comment: Why do you want to use those functions? They seem relatively useless to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think that you can only protect a few bytes from that article ? The API is quite simple - remember that the encryption doesn't happen in place, a new array is returned with the encrypted content.

Here is a full example of using [`ProtectedData.Protect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect.aspx) and [back](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.unprotect.aspx):

```
void Main()
{
    string data  = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    buffer = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(buffer, null, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
    // Data is now protected.

    // Unprotect
    buffer = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(buffer, null, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);  
    string decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    Debug.Assert(data == decrypted);
}
```

Also, you will need to add a reference to the System.Security assembly.

Comment: is it possible to store the encrypted bytes in my app, instead of encrypting it in my app

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ... Yes, of course you can store the encrypted bytes, and decrypt them later - is that what you need ?

Comment: yes, that is what i need, how and where do i store the encrypted bytes in my application code or file system

Comment: The simplest way is to use a FileStream to store on disk, nothing magical here. You just need to remember the protection scope (you won't be able to move that file between machines because the DPAPI restricts access to either the current user or current machine (the DataProtectionScope parameter). If you have trouble with storing the data, I suggest you make another question on SO with a specific question.